# How can I make my code more reusable for logging in my controllers

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core-mvc, refactoring

I am using same code for every controller. OnActionExecuting is called every time before action executed.
how can i refactor the given code?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        private readonly ILogger<AccountController> logger;
        private string userId;
        private string path;

        public AccountController(
            ILogger<AccountController> logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            userId =  User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier) 
            path = $"{context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value}[{context.HttpContext.Request.Method}]";
            logger.LogDebug($"{path} started. User(id): {userId}.");
        }
}
```

Example of how i am using it:

```
logger.LogInformation($"{path} Was approved for User(id) + {userId}.");
```

Comment: you could also consider using action filters instead

Comment: Read up on it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#implementation

Comment: @Nkosi Thank you! I  have tried to use actionfilters but i can't get property from it. I need userId and path for other loggs.

Comment: You have access to the HttpContext within the action filter. This means you will be able to extract the current user and request path similar to the example you showed in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a BaseController :

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{

    private readonly ILogger<BaseController> logger;
    private string userId;
    private string path;

    public BaseController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<BaseController>>();
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        userId =  User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier) 
        path = $"{context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value}[{context.HttpContext.Request.Method}]";
        logger.LogDebug($"{path} started. User(id): {userId}.");
    }
}
```

Then, create HomeController

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public HomeController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : base(serviceProvider)
    { 
    }

}
```